# draggable image on a draggable background (how to control which fires)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am making a jigsaw puzzle with drag-and-drop pieces as well as zoom/pan functionality, using HTML/CSS/JQuery. For panning, I wanted to allow a user to drag on the background (anywhere there isn't a puzzle piece) to move. This all works fine, but when a user is dragging a puzzle piece (using jQuery draggable) here, the mousedown and mousemove events for dragging the background fires first. I do disable the panning as soon as the draggable event on the puzzle pieceis detected, but this still causes the background to 'jut' ever so slightly, leading to a jerky small panning movement before the piece can be dragged appropriately.

If you have any ideas how to combat this, please do share. Thanks!

Comment: Link to demo on jsfiddle or similar? Offhand it sounds like event bubbling.

Comment: actually, I may have a solution. What if I just attach a hover/unhover over puzzle pieces to check a flag? This way if I am over an object then I can just not do anything on mousedown for panning.

Comment: Did you try checking the target element in `event.target`?